# Assign value received from @escaping to instance variable in another class in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, escaping

I believe that I misunderstood some conception in Swift and can assign received array to my instance variable. Can somebody explain why overall my `announcementsList` array has 0 elements?

**UIViewController.swift**

```
var announcementsList: [Announcement] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   api.getAnnouncements(){ announcements in  //<- announcements is array which has 12 elements
       for ann in announcements{
          self.announcementsList.append(ann)
       }
   }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return announcementsList.count   //<- have 0 here
}
```

**API.swift**

```
func getAnnouncements(completion:  @escaping ([Announcement]) -> ()){
    var announcements: [Announcement] = []
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.ca/announcements")!

    let task = self.session.dataTask(with: url) {
        data, response, error in
        if let data = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            guard let announcements_json = json!["announcements"] as? [[String: Any]]
                else { return }

            for announcement in announcements_json{
                let title = announcement["title"] as! String
                let desc = announcement["description"] as! String
                announcements.append(Announcement(title: title,desc: desc))
            }

        }
        completion(announcements)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

P.S.: In my defence, I should say code works in Java pretty well

**UPD**

In **UIViewController.swift** if glance inside my `announcementsList` in `viewWillDisappear()` I will get my objects there. So I assume that `tableView()` started count elements earlier then they became reassigned in `viewDidLoad()`.

The question now how to assign objects inide `viewDidLoad()` to a new array faster than `tableView()` start count them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var announcementsList: [Announcement] = [] {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   api.getAnnouncements { announcements in
      self.announcementsList = announcements
   }
}
```

Comment: It makes `Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'` error

Comment: Never mind. I just added an outlet to my tableView:
`@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` . Not sure it's a good decision or not, but it works at least.

Comment: Yes, if you're using storyboards it's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The operation is asynchronous , so the tableView reloads when the VC appears and at that moment the response isn't yet return

```
for ann in announcements{
   self.announcementsList.append(ann)
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

BTW why not

```
self.announcementsList = announcements
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Also don't know current thread of callback , so do

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.announcementsList = announcements
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I tried `self.announcementsList = announcements` but it didn't help as well

Comment: this isn't a global varaible it's instance variable , BTW what type of response array

Comment: also Did you set delegate and dataSource of table to self ??

Comment: what current problem ??

Comment: thkx, updated. Type of `announcements` same as the type of `announcementsList` -> Announcement

Comment: The problem is I can't add objects from `announcements`  to `announcementsList`

Comment: to do that  they should be in same type

Comment: They both are the same type

Comment: are you sure the webService is giving to you a valid response?

Comment: @Sh_Khan added the code of the `getAnnouncements` function

Comment: I think this should compile , tried to add print statements inside the callback to track response ??

Comment: I was the first what I did. I got the point ->  `tableView()` just started count my elements earlier then my objects reassign them in `viewDidLoad()`